# When to use Javascript prototype instead of regular object format

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

In Javascript, there are two ways you can define an object's properties:

**First way**

```
var myObject = {
  property1: function () {..},
  property2: function () {..}
};
```

**Second Way**

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.prototype.property1 = function() {...};
myObject.prototype.property2 = function() {...};
```

When I looked up `prototype` online, I found that it is used to add properties to an existing object. So, if you have an object which was created by a third party library, then you can add extra properties to it. What I don't understand is why you would use `prototype` for custom objects created in your own code. However, I have found many times (especially in Drupal core) that `prototype` is used this way. Why is this?

Comment: Please first search before asking something that was asked several times before, even on StackOverflow.

Comment: Are you familiar with *prototypal inheritance*?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work

Comment: @trincot I had looked around and must not have looked deep enough. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript is a great resource, thanks!